# Reading a file line-by-line / field-by-field (pipe-delimited) in powershell

Tags: shell, powershell

Actually beginner in PowerShell. I want to convert shell script into powershell.

I have `sample.txt` file which contains 3 lines. I want to select each word in line to different variable and which variables are need to use in next if condition.

```
get-content sample.txt 
wordone|secondword|thridword|fourthword
wordone1|secondword1|thridword1|fourthword1
wordone2|secondword2|thridword2|fourthword2
```

I have already shell script:

```
grep "^[^#]" ./sample.txt > test.txt

for line in `cat test.txt`
do
    dir=`echo $line | cut -d'|' -f1`
    metadata_name=`echo $line | cut -d'|' -f2`
    metadata_file=`echo $line | cut -d'|' -f3`
    config_file=`echo $line | cut -d'|' -f4`

    if [ "${config_file}" != "" ]
    then
cp ${dir}.xml  folder1/.
```

Please help me how to convert shell to powershell.

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Comment: I can't speak to PowerShell, but the original bash script is actually both inefficient and buggy. `while IFS='|' read -r dir metadata_name metadata_file config_file; do test -n "$config_file" && cp -- "$dir.xml" folder1/.; done` would be not just shorter and lower-overhead to run (using only commands built into the shell itself for parsing, rather than invoking external `cat` and `cut`; and avoiding the need to fork off subshells) but considerably more correct.

Comment: See [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for advice on correctly reading a file line-by-line in bash. I'd actually hazard that you'll probably be able to do something similar in PowerShell, doing the read and parse natively without *needing* to read the output of any other commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
$textfile = get-content "sample.txt"
$sample = "sample.txt"


for ($i=0;$i -lt $textfile.count;$i++){
    $textrow = ($textfile[$i]).split("|")

    $dir = $textrow[0]
    $metadata_name = $textrow[1]
    $metadata_file = $textrow[2]
    $config_file = $textrow[3]

   If($config_file -ne ""){
        New-Item $dir/ConfigurationPlan -type directory -force
        $sample | Out-File "$dir/ConfigurationPlan/$($config_file)_sample.xml"
   }

}
```

Comment: Thanks.. it is working for me. One more thing i need is while copy

Comment: entire path structure into Build directory like shell script. Please suggest possible way in powershell                                                                                                 cp --parents -r ${variable1}/ConfigurationPlan/${varaible4}_sample}.xml  pwd /Build

Comment: No. Actually i want to copy same A/B/C  structure into other folder New   if [ "${config_file}" != "" ]
    then
  cp --parents -r ${dir}/ConfigurationPlan/${config_file}_env.xml Presentworkingdirectory/Build
        ${ANT_HOME}/bin/ant -f ${ORACLE_HOME}/soa/bin/ant-b2b-util.xml b2bconfig -Dmode=publishandimport -Dexportfile="presentworkingdirectory/Artifact/${dir}/${metadata_file}" -Dconfigplan="presentworkingdirectory/Artifact/${dir}/ConfigurationPlan/${config_file}_env.xml" -Dgeneratedexportfile="presentworkingdirectory/Build/${dir}/Tokenised_${metadata_file}"

Comment: else
  cp --parents -r ${dir}/${metadata_file} Presentworkingdirectory/Build
  ${ANT_HOME}/bin/ant -f ${ORACLE_HOME}/soa/bin/ant-b2b-util.xml b2bimport -Dlocalfile=false -Dexportfile="Presentworkingdirectory/Artifact/${dir}/${metadata_file}" 
    fi

Comment: You may want to add that to your question. i can't understand the way it is written in the comments. Also I did make a few changes. Check to see if that works for you or if that is what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'd treat your `.\sample.txt` file as a csv file and use Import-Csv with `-Delimiter '|'` and `-Header dir,metadata_name,metadata_file,config_file` parameters.
Then iterate the lines checking for `dir` and existence of the file to copy.

```
$Sample = Import-Csv sample.txt -delimiter '|' -Header dir,metadata_name,metadata_file,config_file
$Sample
"----"
ForEach ($Line in $Sample){
    if ($Line.config_file -ne ""){
        $File = "$($line.dir).xml"
        "config_file is $($Line.config_file) checking $File"
        if (Test-Path $File){
            Copy-ITem -Path $File -Destination "folder1\" -whatif
        }
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
> Q:\Test\2017\07\21\SO_45239319.ps1

dir      metadata_name metadata_file config_file
---      ------------- ------------- -----------
wordone  secondword    thridword     fourthword
wordone1 secondword1   thridword1    fourthword1
wordone2 secondword2   thridword2    fourthword2
----
config_file is fourthword checking wordone.xml
config_file is fourthword1 checking wordone1.xml
config_file is fourthword2 checking wordone2.xml
```

If your output looks OK, remove the `-WhatIf` parameter of Copy-Item